# Animating new additions to a generated list with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `<ul>` of elements like this:

```
<ul id="task-list">
  <li class="task"></li>
  <li class="task"></li>
  <li class="task"></li>
  <li class="task"></li>
</ul>
```

Every time a `.task` is changed, added, or removed, I generate the entire `<ul>` again through a Handlebars template and display it with `.html()`:

```
function addHTML(allTasks) {
  var tasks = compileTemplate(allTasks);
  return $('#task-list').html(tasks);
}

function compileTemplate(allTasks) {
  var source = $('#task-template').html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  return template({
    tasks: allTasks
  });
}
```

The list uses [Slip.js](https://pornel.net/slip/) for reordering, and new items are added at the top of the list. The height of each item could be anything.

Is it possible to have a CSS animation for new additions where the list "slides down" to pop in the new task, or will I need to change my logic to add each task to an existing list, instead of generating the whole `<ul>` each time?

Comment: _"Is it possible to have a height or fade animation for new additions to the list using CSS"_ How are additions to `#task-list` determined ?

Comment: The animation you're aiming for sounds possible with some fancy JavaScript, but to my knowledge, there's been no CSS animations that apply to document layout (ie, transitioning an element into a new position that moves down others). At the very least, your JavaScript would have to leave the existing list in place, and figure out what has been changed, in order to animate correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with some simple jquery functions, although AngularJS would look much cleaner. A little example for adding and removing elements with **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbL09kdt/1/)** example.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="task-list">
    <li class="task"><button class="remove">remove</button>Lorem</li>
  <li class="task"><button class="remove">remove</button>Ipsum</li>
  <li class="task"><button class="remove">remove</button>Dilor</li>
  <li class="task"><button class="remove">remove</button>Test</li>
</ul>

<li class="task" id="hidden-task"><button class="remove">remove</button>Test</li>
<button class="add">add last Child</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
//.remove is class of your remove button, task is the list element
$('.remove', '.task').on('click', function(){
    var li = $(this).parent();
    li.slideToggle({
    'complete':function(){
        li.remove()
    }
    });
})

//use hidden element as dummy
var element = $('#hidden-task');

//cache tasklist
var taskList = $('#task-list');
$('.add').on('click', function(){
    //create a deep clone
    var clone = element.clone(1,1);
    taskList.append(clone);
    setTimeout(function(){
    clone.slideToggle()
    }, 200);
});

var nth = 2;
$('.c2th').on('click', function(){
    var clone = element.clone(1,1);
    $('li').eq(nth-1).after(clone);
    setTimeout(function(){
    clone.slideToggle()
    }, 200);
});
```